# Raspbmc: How can I open the terminal?

Tags: networking, raspbmc, terminal

I already searched how it's possible to open the terminal on Raspbmc, however none of the two methods I know seems to work. I've read that I can open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> but nothing happens.

Theoretically the second method says to click on `Shutdown` option and then on `Exit` and wait until opens a "white" screen, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This method neither works and a blank screen appears. The only thing that works is the combination of <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which restarts the system.

What is causing that and why I can't see the terminal?

Also I managed to connect successfully through SSH with [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), but I did something wrong in network settings, and now I can't connect. That's why I need to open the terminal.

I'm running Raspbmc.

## EDIT

Unfortunately, it does not work with any of the solutions that I found, so I decided to remove this OS and move to Xbian. I really don't know what was causing this...

Comment: have you tried `Ctr`+`Alt`+`Backspace`?

Comment: ctrl+alt+backspace restarts X. Doesn't the pi use some kind of openbox desktop? If so try alt+t or ctrl+alt+t (gnome variant).

Comment: Maybe there is a [SSH terminal plugin for OSMC on Raspberri Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29849/ssh-terminal-plugin-for-osmc-on-raspberri-pi)

Comment: Though you've ditched RaspBMC did you try to run `sudo /sbin/agetty 38400 tty10 linux` in a terminal? It should (imperfectly though) give you a text terminal, provided you can switch to it. The command will last until the end of the login session. I haven't tried this on a RaspBMC (or OSMC) distribution but I assume those distros have kept text login capabilities. At least you'll know if there's a `/etc/inttab` file...

Comment: how about `Alt+F2` and then `LXTerminal`

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl-Alt key combos won't work on Raspbmc because XBMC running on the Pi runs under OpenGL directly on the framebuffer, and not under X11 like it would on a regular Linux desktop.

In order to get a terminal in Raspbmc you need to quite out of XBMC without powering off. This should be possible by going to the little power icon and selecting "Exit".

Comment: I know this question is old, but while this works temporarily the pi reboots within a few seconds. So not much of a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> Theoretically the second method says to click on `Shutdown` option and then on `Exit` and wait until opens a "white" screen, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This works on my installation of OSMC (apart from "white" is not white but the moment when the OSMC screen re-appears)

I use this to `startx` for my `LXDE` session as described in [my comment here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9312/29214)