# SSH terminal plugin for OSMC on Raspberri Pi

Tags: ssh, raspbmc

Is there a way to open a console inside [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/) with a HDMI screen connected?

I know, I could connect via SSH from another computer, but I would prefer to edit the server stand-alone.

Note: I managed to find out the IP of my osmc with [zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/) scanning the local Network, and then logged in with the latest version of [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (username: osmc , password: osmc) an older Version of Putty didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the power button (bottom left corner) and select `exit`.

Selecting `exit` will not shutdown the system but just exits back to a terminal. Running `startx` will then bring back the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for supplying this tip - could you elaborate in your answer whether this means that OSMC/Kodi gets shutdown (and how to get back into OSMC/Kodi once you're done with the terminal activities?)

Answer (score 0):

you can install "screen" via ssh.

sudo apt-get install screen

then google how to add custom menu entry's in osmc..

not a complete answer, cause my english is not good enugh to write down a complete howto, but maybe it helps you a bit

Comment: The program `screen` wouldn't work, but maybe xterm or such a graphical ui. If it is possible to open in via menu. I will try that